# Android Retrofit session - cookies

Tags: android, session, cookies, retrofit

I am using retrofit to deserialize json request from web server and I need to create a session (cookie?) in my app (which should expire in 120 min). The problem is I don't know how to implement it.

```
private RestAdapter adapter = RestAdapter.Builder().setClient(????).setServer("http://192.168.0.1").build();
```

This session should persist only if the application is running.

Min SDK requirement is 8

Comment: Hey you ever figure this out?

Comment: I moved to loopj http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ It's much more better.

Comment: i answered a similar question here.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25851781/1677824

Answer (score 2):

Ok,you know the retrofit actually uses the okhttp inside the framework.

And you should know the "Interceptor"

When you init a okhttp in retrofit, you should invoke addInterceptor, just like this:

```
 OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        builder.retryOnConnectionFailure(true);
        builder.connectTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        builder.writeTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        builder.readTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        builder.addInterceptor(new ZCommonIntercepter());
```

Custom your own Intercepter extends Intercepter.

And get the sessionId by response.header("Set-cookie") save it as a Constant or something in your memory.

Every request after this you should remove the original header("cookie")

and addHeader (the thing that you have already saved)

I'm sorry that i'm not a native english speaker. If you can not understand me. I will just give you some keywords, you can google it.

---Key words---

- interceptor in okhttp
- cookies in request header or response header