# Retrieve incoming cookies with Retrofit

Tags: android, cookies, retrofit

I need to save an incoming cookie in order to subscribe further requests. I know I could do something like: `CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));` though I'm not sure if it's completely appropriate/safe to write things like this.

There's already a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22425993/how-to-retrieve-cookies-in-android-retrofit), yet it's unanswered.

Thanks.